# Word for the possibility of being many things at once

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for a term describing the possibility of an entity to be seen many different things at the same time. The general concept of being able to categorize an entity into several context-dependent abstractions.

**A car is not only a car, but can be:**

- A vehicle
- A toy
- A risk
- A pollutant
- A Faraday's cage
- A source of taxation
- A trap
- A tool
- A weapon

**Words that does not capture the proper meaning:**

- A car is flexible.
- A car is adaptable.
- A car is versatile.

**Words that might work**

- Multifaceted
- Multi-sided

**I need a general noun for describing this property in a ontological context**

- Multifacetedness (Does not sound natural)
- Multi-sidedness (Even less natural)

**Let's try some sentences**

*You could be anything you want, [multifacetedness] is universal.*

*We are not allowing [multifacetedness] in this game, you can only be one thing at a time.*

*Philosophers all agree, [multifacetedness] is fundamental in how we perceive and make sense of the world.*

Is there a better word for this?

Comment: If this is in regards to ontology, you may want to ask on the Philosophy SE site.  There are more philosophy domain experts there...

Comment: I had no idea that the word *car* was so [arbitrary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arbitrary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Multiplicity** might suit you. From [Merriam-Webster's full definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiplicity):

> **multiplicity *noun***
>   *plural* **multiplicities
>
>   1 a** :  the quality or state of being multiple or various
>   . . .
>   *Shakespeare's works seem to encompass the full **multiplicity** of
>   human experience.*

Philosophers and psychologists do use this term, though perhaps not in exactly the way you want. See, for example, [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/what-is-multiplicity-for-deleuze) and its answers on the Philosophy StackExchange (content is above my pay grade, so I'm not clear on how closely this lines up with your ideas) and [this entry on multiplicity](https://di.org.au/about-multiplicity/) on the Dissociative Association's website.

At least one psychologist appears to be thinking along your lines:

> MULTIPLICITY presents an entirely new view of our selves. Instead of
>   seeing each person as a single personality, Carter argues that **we all
>   consist of multiple characters**, each one with its own viewpoint,
>   emotions and ambitions. The mother who feeds breakfast to her
>   children, for example, has quite different concerns and opinions from
>   the woman taking part in a boardroom discussion two hours later, and
>   from the woman she will be with her husband that night. Yet all three
>   may share the same body, and none is any more "authentic" than
>   another. ([Amazon book blurb for *Multiplicity: The New Science of Personality, Identity, and the Self* by Rita Carter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0046LUI0G), bolding added.)

Note that this definition pertains more to how your car views its own many roles and identities, rather than how you or I perceive the car, but I think it could easily encompass both.

Answer (score 6):

## *multifacetedness, multifaceted, multi- + facets*

The real word for being multi-sided and thus having many fac**e**ts is [*multifac**e**ted*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multifaceted#English), correctly spelled with an *e* not an *i*, and whose second, figurative sense Wiktionary gives as:

> Having many aspects; nuanced or diverse.
>
> > *Joanne was a multifaceted individual; she knew how to bargain both with Wall Street brokers and push-cart vendors.*

I don’t where you came up with that weird spelling that nobody would be able to make any sense out of, because **you have effaced the *face* part** of it with your spelling error.  In speech it would of course make no difference, but in writing you’ve lost the underlying root and so produced something confusing.

The OED attests *multifacetedness* as a noun derived from *multifaceted*, but I agree that it might come off as awkward; it is not an especially common word.

As I mentioned to the asker in a comment, I completely agree with him that I like the sound of neither *multifacetedness* nor *multisidedness*.  One should always be wary of piling up ever-increasing suffixes to derive “new” words like this. It sounds really clunky, so if there’s a simpler word available, then one probably should. See also [*nominalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization), which is sometimes useful but too often a hallmark of terrible writing and military bureaucracy.

Comment: Thank you for pointing our my spelling mistake, as a non-native English speaker I'm especially grateful when people make me aware of the mistakes I do.

Comment: @Alex In this case the key to spelling it right relies on understanding the etymological connection between a cut gemstone’s different faces and the English words *face* and *facing*.  See also [*facet joints*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facet_joint). French also has the word *facette*, but we simplified its spelling in English by shortening it up a bit. This by the way is one reason used to justify retaining certain spellings in English: to preserve etymological relationships between words that would be otherwise hidden.

Answer (score 4):

I think the term that may fit your sentences is ***[versatile](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/versatility)*** or ***versatility***:

> - capable of or adapted for turning easily from one to another of various tasks, fields of endeavor, etc.:

The Free Dictionary

Comment: I agree that [*versatile*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/versatile) is far less taxing of eye and tongue than is [*multifacetness*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/multifaceted).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this is not working for me since it's highly associated with abilities and flexibility together in a utilitarian context. I'm in a ontological context, and the meaning *Philosophers all agree, versatility is fundamental in how we perceive and make sense of the world.* is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

How about *multifariousness*?

> [*mul·ti·far·i·ous*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=multifarious&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8):
>   many and of various types; having many varied parts or aspects [Google
>   search]

It's word that Nietzsche and Nietzsche scholars have used, especially in regard to Nietzsche's multifariousness of the self, i.e., of ones inner drives. Google "multifarious Nietzsche".

Answer (score 1):

I found a word that I'm very comfortable with: [Multimorphism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multimorphism).

> You could be anything you want, *multimorphism* is universal.
>
> We are not allowing *multimorphism* in this game, you can only be
>   one thing at a time.
>
> Philosophers all agree, *multimorphism* is fundamental in how we
>   perceive and make sense of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***polymorphism***. From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polymorphism):

> the quality or state of existing in or assuming different forms:

Although the word has been mainly co-opted by the Object Oriented Programming crowd, it's a perfectly valid English word.

In another technical context, Sigmund Freud used the term ***[polymorphous perversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphous_perversity)*** to refer to sexual behavior outside of accepted norms.

It also has technical applications in material science, biology and genetics.

Answer (score 1):

*Duality*

"the quality or state of having two different or opposite parts or elements" (Merriam Webster).  The important part here is "different," not "opposite."

Your examples:

> You could be anything you want, duality is universal.
>
> We are not allowing duality in this game, you can only be one thing at a time.
>
> Philosophers all agree, duality is fundamental in how we perceive and make sense of the world.

In this last one, it might work better to say, *Philosophers all agree, the duality of (such-and-so) is fundamental in how we perceive and make sense of the world.*

For example, something like *the duality of objective and subjective reality.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the existing phrase "a car is not only a car but is "multifaceted"  or "multi-sided" is missing an explanatory ingredient. I believe the word"multip[licity ios bettter than "multifaceted" or multi-sided. These words imply that cars have many many different outside surface forms, whereas the text refers to the car's utility - its many different innate functions and effects, some of which are nefarious. "Multiplicity" is better. In any case, further words are needed. I suggest the phrase should say " A car is not only a car but can have a multiplicity of functions and effects, both good and bad:" (-> list)

Answer (score 0):

How about **dual** or **polyglottal**?

[Monoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monism) and [Dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism) seem to be two major ideas in the ontological context.

Since you are also stating **multi-** as a hint word for both your not so well fitting words - **poly...** fits well in the ontological context of being, which explains polyglot-polyglottal a good word pair to use.

If you could give an excerpt from your text, we could come up with better or well sounding suggestions/alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The word you may be looking for is either **polymorphic** or **extensible**.

pol·y·mor·phic
/ˌpälēˈmôrfik/
adjective
occurring in several different forms, in particular with reference to species or genetic variation.

ex·ten·si·ble
/ikˈstensəb(ə)l/
adjective
designed to allow the addition of new capabilities and functionality.

Hope these help!

Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/polymorphic
Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/extensible

Comment: You should include a source for your definitions.